# Сравнить строку и запрос

Tags: строки, bash

Как распознать заголовок ответа(200, 404, 302...)? Кусок кода:

```
ans=curl --cookie cookies.txt -Is "http://adress.com"| head -n 1
if [ $ans -eq 'HTTP/1.1 200 OK' ] 
then echo "$num" >> OK.txt
fi
```

Comment: `[` — это программа (обычно располагается в `/usr/bin`, но ещё чаще оболочка сама выполняет её как внутреннюю команду), соответственно, её имя должно быть отделено от списка аргументов пробелом. и все аргументы отделяются пробелами друг от друга, в том и числе и последний (обязателен для программы `[`) — символ `]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

согласно [rfc7230](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230#section-3.1.2) статусная строка в ответе имеет синтаксис:

> The first line of a response message is the status-line, consisting
> of the protocol version, a space (SP), the status code, another
> space, a possibly empty textual phrase describing the status code,
> and ending with CRLF.

> ```
> status-line = HTTP-version SP status-code SP reason-phrase CRLF
> ```

> The status-code element is a 3-digit integer code describing the
> result of the server's attempt to understand and satisfy the client's
> corresponding request.

т.е. вам надо из первой строки извлечь три цифры, расположенные между первым и вторым пробелами. сделать это можно разными способами. например:

```
sed -r 's/^[^ ]+ ([0-9]{3}) .*/\1/;q'
```

---

```
$ curl -Is https://ru.stackoverflow.com | sed -r 's/^[^ ]+ ([0-9]{3}) .*/\1/;q'
200
$ curl -Is http://ru.stackoverflow.com | sed -r 's/^[^ ]+ ([0-9]{3}) .*/\1/;q'
301
```

---

сохранить в переменную всё, что команда отправит в *stdout*, можно с помощью [*command substitution*](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_03):

```
переменная=$(команда)
```

или (для работы в древних несовместимых с posix оболочках типа входящей в solaris версии ниже 11):

```
переменная=`команда`
```